# Where is the problem in my code for generating a bitmap from a byte array?

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc

i create bitmap from that byte array, and setBitmap on my picture control
However, no image is displayed.
Where is the problem in my code for generating a bitmap from a byte array?

[OnInitDialog]

```
PICTURE_MY.GetWindowRect(&rect); //PICTURE_MY is my picture control
MAX_CANVAS_W = rect.right - rect.left;
MAX_CANVAS_H = rect.bottom - rect.top;
layerOne = new BYTE[3*((MAX_CANVAS_W-2)*(MAX_CANVAS_H-2))];
pitch = MAX_CANVAS_W - 2;

int count = 0;
while (count < 3 * ((MAX_CANVAS_W - 2) * (MAX_CANVAS_H - 2)))
{
    layerOne[count] = 255;
    count++;
}
```

[OnPaint]

```
HBITMAP h_bitmap = CreateBitmap(pitch, MAX_CANVAS_H - 2, 1, 24, layerOne);
CImage image;
image.Attach(h_bitmap);

PICTURE_MY.SetBitmap(image);
```

When I wrote the following code, it worked well, but it's too slow for my use case, and I don't want to use it

```
        CClientDC dc(this);
        for (int y = 0; y < MAX_CANVAS_H - 2; y++) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < pitch; x++) 
            {
                COLORREF color = RGB(layerOne[3*(y*pitch+x)], layerOne[3 * (y * pitch + x)+1], layerOne[3 * (y * pitch + x)+2]);
                dc.SetPixel(PICTURE_LEFTTOP.x+1 + x, PICTURE_LEFTTOP.y+y+1, color);
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Regardless of how you create the bitmap, you should not be creating it in an OnPaint event. Create it one time when you create the byte array. Recreate the bitmap only when the bytes change. Assign the bitmap one to your UI control only when the bitmap changes. Let the control paint itself normally, it will draw its current bitmap for you.

Comment: 1. `SetBitmap()` shouldn't be called in response to a `WM_PAINT` message (`OnPaint()`), instead it should be called when you want to change the image displayed by the control, eg during initialization - the control handles all painting (unless it's an owner-drawn one). 2. Raster lines in the buffer  must be word-aligned, so you may have to pad it (+1 byte if the number of bytes is odd); the line length is `(3*(MAX_CANVAS_W-2)+1)/2*2` and the buffer-size (3*(MAX_CANVAS_W-2)+1)/2*2*(MAX_CANVAS_H-2) (multiplication operators have a left-to-right associativity). What does `CreateBitmap()` return?